# In c# how i can convert from object to float

Tags: c#, datagridview

I get the following error when trying to convert an object to float:

> System.InvalidCastException: The cast specified is invalid.

menu[i].weight = (float)dataGridView1[j, i].Value;

Comment: Is `dataGridView1[j, i].Value` an actual float value? It doesn't seem to be from the error - what is the value of that variable?

Comment: Try `menu[i].weight = (float)(int) dataGridView1[j, i].Value;` if it is - does that work?

Comment: Value is 100% not float

Comment: What is the *actual* value it is failing on? Anyway, using `(float)Convert.ToDouble(..)` might just “fix it” by using various runtime checks. (This will still fail if the value is DBNull.Value and it will return 0 if the value is null.)

Comment: use try parse. google about a syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're converting, as others have stated in the comments, is not truly a `float` - but that might be confusing, because *it might look like* a `float` - here's an example of a possible scenario:

```cs
object maybeFloat = 1.25;  // looks like a float, but is actually a double!
float wontWork = (float)maybeFloat;
```

The above cast will fail, throwing an `InvalidCastException` - because the actual item stored (technically known in C# as *boxed*, in the case of `struct`s, such as `int`, `float`, `double`, as well as custom `struct` types) is a `double`, not a `float`. There are several "fixes":

- Store a float:

```cs
object someFloat = 1.25f; // Notice the `f` after the number - that's a float!
float willWork = (float)someFloat;
```

... but that's not always possible - the data might be coming from some external source, such as a database, etc. In that case, `float.Parse` to the rescue:

```cs
object maybeFloat = 1.25; // Still not a float... but can be parsed as one!
float willWork = float.Parse(maybeFloat.ToString()); // float.Parse requires a string, 
                                                     // hence the `.ToString()` call
```

This will work if the object contains a value that is in fact parseable into a `float` datatype. So, the above example works for parsing a boxed `double` into a `float` (notice, some data loss may occur - not in the above example, but in general, because `float` is a smaller data type than `double`). This will also work if the value stored is a `string` (as an aside, `string`s are not boxed, because they are reference types). Perhaps strangely, the `.ToString()` call is still required - because there is no *implicit conversion* from `object` to `string`:

```cs
object maybeFloat = "1.25"; // Still not a float... but can be parsed as one!
float willWork = float.Parse(maybeFloat.ToString()); // no implicit conversion, 
                                                     // hence the `.ToString()` call
```

... but what if the value stored is really, really, not a float at all? Well, then `float.Parse` will fail, most likely throwing a `FormatException`, indicating that the supplied value is really not parseable into a `float` datatype. You can catch the exception with a `try/catch` block:

```cs
object maybeFloat = "one point two five"; // hmmm... that won't parse into a float!
float result = default;
try
{
   result = float.Parse(maybeFloat.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException _)
{
   // Handle error here!
}
```

...however, there's a better way - `float.TryParse`:

```cs
object maybeFloat = "one point two five"; // will fail to parse!
bool isSuccessfullyParsed = float.TryParse(maybeFloat.ToString(), out var result);

if (!isSuccessfullyParsed)
{
   // Handle error
}
else
{
   // `result` will contain the properly parsed float value
}
```

Ok, this should give you a pretty good idea of what's happening in your specific case. Final note, the `.Parse` and `.TryParse` methods exist on all .NET numeric types - `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, even `BigInteger`  - so same technique applies to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float.TryParse` and pass object convert `ToString()` as parameter. Please see below.

```cs
object obj = 2.111;
float height;
if (float.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out height))
{
   //success
   Console.WriteLine(height);
}
else
{
    //failed
}
```